# Thread in C++11 not in class member

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm recently using C++11 threads and I have a question about something (strange for me) happened.
I created a method inside a class, able to start thread. The starting thread method and the callback function of the thread are class methods.
To clarify, in my Person.cpp file I have:

```
void Person::callbackForThread(){
    ...
}


void Person::startThread(){
    this call threads. Something like:
    thread(callbackForThread);
}
```

The problem is that C++11 doesn't allow me to declare these two function as class methods. This means that if I declare them as normal function, i.e:

```
 void callbackForThread(){
    ...
}


void startThread(){
    this call threads. Something like:
    thread(callbackForThread);
}
```

Everythings works. I would know how could I declare thread and callback inside a class in C++, if it is possible.
For the farther, I have omitted the inclusion of the libraries and the name of the real class. The class shown in this question is fictitious.

Comment: don't think....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Person::callbackForThread` takes an hidden first argument: `this`.

This is where lambdas and `std::bind` come in handy:

```
thread([this]() { this->callbackForThread(); });
```

or

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
thread(std::bind(&Person::callbackForThread, this, _1));
```

---

From krzaq feedback: if `thread` is `std::thread`, it needs to be `detach`ed or saved somehow.

Comment: or just `thread(&Person::callbackForThread, this)`, no need for bind

Comment: Yes, It sound great. You make my day! Thank you

Comment: Why not just `thread(&Person::callbackForThread, this)`? As a side note, this is an expression and it will destroy the thread object at the end of it. If it has not finished by that time (very unlikely), you'll call `std::terminate`.

Comment: @PeterT I'd rather not: 1/ this is true only if we're talking about `std::thread` and not some user-defined `thread` thing. 2/ the use of `std::bind` is idiomatic and well understood by C++ developers. (but yeah, ok, why not)

Comment: Why can I write thread(myCallBackFun), so without the &, if myCallBackFun is a normal function and thread(&Person::myCallBackFun) if myCallBackFun  is a class method? I mean, I understand the Person:: prefix but not the &. Is not implicit that I'm using the reference? as in the first case?

Comment: @BossShell you're taking the adress of a function, the unary `&` operator is expected. The thing is, for free functions, there is a special rule somewhere coming from the C language which allows to omit it. All Hail Compatibility!